# select Query to convert datetime column to UTC

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table in `MYSQL` with 10 columns. The table has a `datetime` column in local time zone.

Now I want to do `select * from table` but want the     `datetime` to display in `UTC` timezone format

How can I get the desired result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use MySQL's function CONVERT_TZ

```
CONVERT_TZ(datetime_column,'[local time zone]','UTC')
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz